# Image in nextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

Hi i have a user profile image coming from the backend, but in case the user does not have a profile Image I want it to have a default profile image , of a two letter (such as Google's).

this is the next image:

```
              <Image
            className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
            src={row.original.imgUrl.length >= 0 ? row.original.imgUrl : createImageFromInitials(500, row.original.name, getRandomColor())}
            alt=""
            width={40}
            height={40}
          />
```

the error I am receiving:

```
Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | StaticImport'.
```

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | StaticImport'.

I have a file called getInitials.ts

```
export const getInitials = (name: string) => {
let initials;
const nameSplit = name.split(" ");
const nameLength = nameSplit.length;
if (nameLength > 1) {
  initials =
    nameSplit[0].substring(0, 1) +
    nameSplit[nameLength - 1].substring(0, 1);
} else if (nameLength === 1) {
  initials = nameSplit[0].substring(0, 1);
} else {
  return "";
}

return initials.toUpperCase();
```

};

```
  export const createImageFromInitials = (size: number, name: string | null | undefined, color: string) => {
if (name === null || name === undefined) return;

name = getInitials(name);

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
if (!context) return null;
canvas.width = canvas.height = size;

context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
context.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);

context.fillStyle = `${color}50`;
context.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
context.fillStyle = color;
context.textBaseline = 'middle';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.font = `${size / 2}px Rubik`;

if (typeof name === 'string') {
  context.fillText(name, size / 2, size / 2);
}

return canvas.toDataURL();
```

};

How to handle the error correctly?

Comment: is `src` casing error?

Comment: yes. I was using tutorial and now I see I use the DOM and not  VDOM, but I will change that. the SRC is causing the error